# Published products on Wordpress successfully, but products not appearing under category

Tags: php, wordpress, content-management-system

I am having an issue with my website (we use wordpress). I created a new category with new products, and I've made sure to set everything correctly on the editor (default display type, status, visibility, etc) but the products don’t appear in the actual site.

In the menu I can see the new category (5) - which means there are 5 products inside, but when clicked, there is nothing there. And if I type the product permalink on search engine it also appears. Just the product under categories is not there, does anyone has a solution for this?

[Screenshot of the page with issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JqmUR.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Double check the visibility status on each of these products https://prnt.sc/9NUgowD7qa-K
2. Clear any cache
3. Check you plugins for any compatibility issue
4. Save permalinks again

Comment: I've done all these but still nothing happened. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: @user19682360 The other categories are working fine?
If yes, remove the products from the problematic category and try adding 2-3 products from a working category to the one that is not displaying the products. If this doesn't work, try deleting and add again this category, and save permalinks again. Let me know

Comment: Yes, the other categories are fine. I tried putting an existing product from working category in the one not working and it shows. But when I duplicate this product and publish it on the same/ non working category, it doesn't shows. I think all the recent products I published are not working, I'm not sure why (I double checked, status is published and visibility is catalog & search)